# Can a class in Input element be referenced to a label in html?

Tags: html, css, web

```
<label for="file_upload" class="custom-file_upload z-depth-1">
  <i class="material-icons">&#xE147;</i>
  <p class="button-text"> Upload Here</p>
</label>
  <input class="file_upload" type="file" accept="image/*" name="user_id" />
```

Is it possible to assign the **for="file_upload"** to the class **class="file_upload"** in Input instead of **id="file_upload"**

When I tried it is not working for class but it works for ID. May I know if I have to use some different approach to use class?

Comment: try use data-target="file_upload" instead for="file_upload"

Comment: @AbhishekPandey I saw few more answers on the stack which said it was possible but there were no explanations for the answer. So I came up with this question!

Comment: @DmitriyLishtvan I have tried this, It wasn't working. If it really works, can you elaborate your answer with a fiddle if you don't mind?

Comment: Not with just a label. If you use javascript you can do whatever you want.

Comment: There is no way to associate `label` to `input` with class.

Comment: @Abhishek
i don't understand you write
https://jsfiddle.net/y90vL0n4/ - this is work fine?

Comment: Any references available @Martijn?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Your description is the complete opposite of your title.

Comment: This is a customised input field @DmitriyLishtvan

Comment: Something along the lines of `$('label').on('click', function(){ $('.'+this.for).focus()`

Comment: Hey @Huelfe, I'm looking for possible solution which can be used to refer for="file_upload" in label to class="file_upload" in the Input